# Save pdf in Photo Gallery

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, photo-gallery

I have the pdf file in the Document Directory. I can access it through code easily and show it to user.

But What I exactly want is to **SAVE THE PDF IN PHOTOGALLERY**. So that user can access it without opening my application.

Any help or suggestions please

Comment: You can not save PDF files in the photogallery, the photogallery only supports images/videos.

Comment: Thanks @rckoenes, What is the other way round to store pdf so that it can be accessed later without opening the app

Comment: Well no, other then app allowing the PDF document to be shared to an app that support PDFs. For share file with other app you can use: [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2F%23documentation%2FUIKit%2FReference%2FUIDocumentInteractionController_class%2FReference%2FReference.html&ei=31f2UZGFBIfJOdKSgNAP&usg=AFQjCNE17Vky3OsDv6jcESIVf1Hu6qB8aw&sig2=GO5b1ZQjK2d_CfrkoiwjOQ&bvm=bv.49784469,d.ZWU)

Answer (score 2):

Convert your PDF into an image and call:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, 
                                    id completionTarget, 
                                   SEL completionSelector, 
                                  void *contextInfo);
```

Comment: and how can I do that? I mean convert pdf to uiimage?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    NSString *path = [FindThePathOfPDF stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOURPDFFILENAME"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the file exists
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {

    CFURLRef pdfURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, (CFStringRef)path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, FALSE);

    CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL);

    CFRelease(pdfURL);

    CGPDFPageRef page;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIImage* imageFromPDF;

    //pass any page number you want
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf,1);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);

    imageFromPDF = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
    CFRelease(pdfURL);

    //pass imageFromPDF to the below function and get it done. 
    /*UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, 
                                id completionTarget, 
                               SEL completionSelector, 
                              void *contextInfo);*/
     }
```

Comment: This code is not working : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623652/how-to-save-pdf-to-photo-gallery

Comment: `imageFromPDF` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Convert an pdf to image :-

```
  CGPDFDocumentRef PDFfile;

        CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("iPhone Sample apps.pdf"), NULL, NULL);
        PDFfile = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
        CFRelease(pdfURL);

 CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(PDFfile,currentpage);

    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context,self.bounds);   
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -1.0, [self bounds].size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page,  kCGPDFArtBox, [self bounds], 0, true));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);    
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
   CGImageRef imgref;
    imgref=CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);      
    image= [[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:imgref ];
```

Now save it in Photo gallery :-

```
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, 
                                id completionTarget, 
                               SEL completionSelector, 
                              void *contextInfo);
```

Hope this helps you !

Comment: please help me on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623652/how-to-save-pdf-to-photo-gallery

Answer (score 0):

In order to manage number of pages you need to do this:

```
CGPDFDocumentRef tempDocRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)tempPdfUrl);
size_t pageCount = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(docRef);
CGContextRef finalPdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)tempPdfUrl, &defaultPageRect, nil);

for (int pageNum = 1; pageNum <= pageCount; pageNum++) {
  CGPDFPageRef tempPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(tempDocRef, pageNum+1);
  CGPDFContextBeginPage(finalPdfContext, nil);
  CGContextDrawPDFPage(finalPdfContext, tempPageRef);

    UIImage *newimage =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newimage, self, nil, nil);


  CGPDFContextEndPage(finalPdfContext);
  CGPDFPageRelease(tempPageRef);
}
```

Comment: Is it in anyways related to my question o.O

Comment: Please help me on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623652/how-to-save-pdf-to-photo-gallery

Comment: @Pankil mentioned link is broken for some reason